# HAXE - Standard library not found. check "HAXE_STD_PATH" enviroment variable

Tags: compiler-errors, haxe, haxeflixel

whenever i try to compile using "lime test windows" (im trying to compile friday night funkin) it gives me this error:
"Standard library not found. Please check your `HAXE_STD_PATH` environment variable (current value: "C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\std")"

i tried setting "HAXE_STD_PATH" enviroment variable to "C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\std", following another posts regarding the error, i also tried setting it as "%HAXEPATH%\std", but im still getting the error... any idea how to fix it??

btw, this is my first post here so im really sorry if i did something wrong

im using windows

edit: just noticed i dont have an std folder on C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\